# How does the stack get attached when you initialize and throw errors separately in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I always see in the documentation that you throw and initialize errors on the same line:

```js
throw new Error("My error");
```

But what if you initialize the error and throw it in separate lines?

For example, when you declare a new instance of error:

```js
const myErrorInstance = new Error("Defined error"); // Initialization
```

And then throw that instance inside of a function:

```js
throw myErrorInstance; // Throwing it
```

Does the stack get attached when you initialize the error instance or when you throw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the error it gets its stack trace.  That's one reason why you want to create it in the same place it is thrown.